# on event does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

My functions are generated dynamically and that's the reason cause I've changed onclick by on("click")
Here is my generated code:

```
<div class="section row" id="divQ1113" style="display: block;">

    <div class="section row principal_question">
    <label>Escoja una opción</label>    </div>

    <div class="section row sub_question">
    </div>

    <div class="section row">
    <select name="Q1113" id="Q1113">
       <option value="">Opciones</option>
       <option value="Q1113_QO3514">SI</option>
       <option value="Q1113_QO3515">NO</option>
   </select>
</div>
</div>
```

And the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    function finputQ1113_QO3514_2808() {

                    var vcond = [3514];
                    var ret =  getQuestionOptionValues("div#divQ1113");
                    if("in" == "in") {
                        if(optAnyInArray(ret, vcond)) {
                            x$("div#divQ550").setStyle("display", "block");
                        }
                        else {

                            clearInputs("div#divQ550");
                            x$("div#divQ550").setStyle("display", "none");
                        }
                    }
                }
                x$("div#Q1113 select").on("click","option#Q1113_QO3514",finputQ1113_QO3514_2808());

                appendToTrigger('finputQ1113_QO3514_2808');
                                function finputQ1113_QO3515_2808() {

                    var vcond = [3514];
                    var ret =  getQuestionOptionValues("div#divQ1113");
                    if("in" == "in") {
                        if(optAnyInArray(ret, vcond)) {
                            x$("div#divQ550").setStyle("display", "block");
                        }
                        else {

                            clearInputs("div#divQ550");
                            x$("div#divQ550").setStyle("display", "none");
                        }
                    }
                }

                x$("div#Q1113 select").on("click","option#Q1113_QO3515",finputQ1113_QO3515_2808());


                appendToTrigger('finputQ1113_QO3515_2808');
```

Maybe there's something in my select? I've change onclick by on("click") because I was thinking that there was the error but isn't it.

Comment: No click event (or any other event) available for `<option>`, only its parent `<select>` can listen to events.

Comment: You've put the `<script>` below the `<div>`?

Comment: The script below the div works fine for elements that are in the page on the first moment, but not for the elements generated dinamically.

Comment: what does this mean x$(), its not an error?

Comment: What is your jQuery version?

Comment: I'm not sure if x$ is an error. This is what I use always...

Comment: I've change the click for this: x$("div#Q1113").on("click","select#Q1113",finputQ1113_QO3514_2808) but it doesn't work.

Comment: @JavierEslavaAlmunia: [Scripts never work for dynamically created elements out of the box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements). Where are your elements created?

Comment: That's true but my elements are created. The only diference between the ones that works an the ones that doesn't work is that some elements are not displaying in the first moment.